# client object model in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin

What is client object model? what does client object model architectural design means in a project.

In my project i have - custom websparts and register js file in webpart and then call all event using jquery and through js file(use soap and json) we communticate to the webservice to get data from the sql database.

Which architecture does my project have. Any name to this kind of architecture.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 1):

**SharePoint Client Side Object Model** or CSOM - it is all about working with SharePoint data and managing SharePoint artifacts (sites, lists, libraries, etc.). CSOM is managed code libraries dedicated to use SharePoint data or manage data outside SharePoint server, in Windows Applications, Web Application, Windows Phone or Silverlight, PowerShell. CSOM also has implementation for JavaScript, which can be used from in client side code.

It is absolutely different from *Server Side Object Model* (SSOM), that is assemblies which only works only on the server where SharePoint Server or Foundation is installed. As you feel already CSOM is more universal then working with SharePoint, but is much less powerful and you can not achieve all features with it.

When you cannot use CSOM .NET assemblies you have an option to use REST, which is kind of CSOM implementation using REST Web Services. REST can be used on any platform.

About your question. You are telling that your JavaScript code is working with some your custom Web Services that access data from database. Is quite common service oriented architecture for client side application. All the business logic is managed on the server side (web services) and representative layer is responsible for showing the data (JavaScript). Though it has nothing to do with SharePoint CSOM directly, on the other hand the architecture is quite similar from the architecture perspective.